# How do I show loading templates for with routes with multiple subscriptions when using iron router 1.0 on meteor?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a project which includes multiple subscriptions which are shared between routes.

I have been using a session variable to indicate when my subscription is loading. I can use these session variables as helpers in my templates and show different loading whirlygigs on my page. This is great when i have a single subscription (although in this case I could use the "loadingTemplate" i guess).

One subscription per route - no problems:

```
    this.route('foos', {
        path: '/foos/;id',
        layoutTemplate: 'pagelayout',
        yieldTemplates: {
            'login_header': {to: 'header'},
            'foos': {to: 'main'},
            'footer': {to: 'footer'}
        },
        waitOn: function () {
            Session.set('fooLoading',true);
            return Meteor.subscribe("foos", this.params.id, Session.get("some-input"), {
                onReady: function() {
                    Session.set('fooLoading',false);
                },
                onError: function (error) {
                    Session.set('fooLoading',false);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

However, with multiple subscriptions I run into trouble because when one subscription is updated the waitOn hook runs, both session variables get set to loading but only one is reset when the subscription is ready.

Two subscriptions per route - problems:

```
    this.route('foobar', {
        path: '/foobar/;id',
        layoutTemplate: 'pagelayout',
        yieldTemplates: {
            'login_header': {to: 'header'},
            'foobar': {to: 'main'},
            'footer': {to: 'footer'}
        },
        waitOn: function () {
            //Can put logic here to figure out which subscription will re-run, but gets hacky and is harder to maintain.
            Session.set('fooLoading',true);
            Session.set('barLoading',true);
            var fooHandle = Meteor.subscribe("foo", this.params.id, Session.get("some-input"), {
                onReady: function() {
                    Session.set('fooLoading',false);
                },
                onError: function (error) {
                    Session.set('fooLoading',false);
                }
            });
            var barHandle = Meteor.subscribe("bar", this.params.id, Session.get("some-other-input"), {
                onReady: function() {
                    Session.set('barLoading',false);
                },
                onError: function (error) {
                    Session.set('barLoading',false);
                }
            });
            return [fooHandle, barHandle];
        }
    });
```

I have been writing logic to decide if each subscription will re-run but this feels hacky and "un-meteor". If there was something on each subscription like onBeforeUpdate that would be awesome. Does such a thing exist or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

You've to use the property `this.ready()`, check this example from Iron Router documentation: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/examples/waiton/waiton.js

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mario. As far as I can see though, it still only allows me to have the route as loading or not. Rather, I would like this for each individual subscription. i.e. if a small part of the page is updating I don't want the whole page to look like it's reloading, just that specific part of the page.

Comment: ´this.ready()´ is for all subscriptions. On subscribe you can add a callback that will update Session/Your Own Reactive Dict and this way you can create a custom loader for each sections/subscriptions. Check the documentation for add the callback to subscribe: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publish_connection

Comment: If I take the example from Evented Mind, how do I know which subscription is *starting* to load. It's easy to know which has *finished* loading, but how do I know if it has *started* to load? `one = new Blaze.ReactiveVar(false);
two = new Blaze.ReactiveVar(false);
Router.route('/many', {
  waitOn: function () {
    // we'll be ready when both one and two are true.
    return [
      function () { return one.get(); },
      function () { return two.get(); }
    ];
  },

  action: function () {
    if (this.ready())
      this.render('Page')
    else
      this.render('LoadingMany');
  }
});`

Comment: As far as I know, there is not way of knowing the percentage of the subscription loading status. I think that you always have to assume that it started loading but it didn't finished yet.

Comment: I don't need to know the percentage. I just need to know if one of the individual subscriptions has started a re-calculation...